# Seperation of method calls for interface implementation in Java , Maybe Using Spring

Tags: java, spring, interface

I have an interface like this :

```
public interface ISmsService {
    //method for vendor A
    String sendSms();

    //method for vendorB
    int sendSms(String loginid);
}
```

The interface describes an overloaded method for two vendors.

I have an vendor A implementation like this :

```
public class VendorAService implements ISmsService{

    @Override
    public String sendSms() {
        return "send msg via vendor A";
    }

    //I want to restrict the usage of this method for vendor B instance at compile time
    @Override
    public int sendSms(String loginid) {
        //I can throw an exception but I do not want to restrict it at runtime.
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And a vendor B implementation like this :

```
public class VendorBService implements ISmsService{

    //I want to restrict the usage of this method for vendor A instance at compile time
    @Override
    public String sendSms() {
        //I can throw an exception but I do not want to restrict it at runtime
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int sendSms(String loginid) {
        return 1000;
    }

}
```

My implementer class is like this :

```
public class User {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ISmsService smsService = new VendorAService();
        smsService.sendSms("12345"); // I want thiş line gives a compile time error. I want only a vendorB type can call this method.

        smsService = new VendorBService();
        smsService.sendSms(); //Same here. I just want vendorA type can call sendSms method without a String parameter
    }

}
```

As I describe in the comment line I want to specify a vendor instance can call just a specific method. I can throw an exception like wrong vendor call at runtime. But if it is possible I want to restrict the behavior at compile time.

Has anybody came across this kind of a problem?

**Does spring has a sollution for this ?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: choose abstract class

Comment: I doubt that spring would have a solution to this, because you don't have an application infrastructure problem here - it's a basic OO modeling issue, too low-level for a framework to tackle. I am not sure if Spring has something to deal specifically with SMS ([this question] suggests that it doesn't).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want the users to be able to call a wrong method, and you would prefer the compiler to do the checking for you, the solution is very easy: remove the interface `ISmsService` altogether. In your case, it does not help at all, introducing incidental complexity without providing any simplification to you in return. The users of the interface need to keep differentiating between the vendors, even though they are handed an interface that is supposedly eliminating the differences.

If you want to get the benefits of the interface, you should unify the two methods in some way, letting the users call the interface method without thinking which vendor is behind it. For example, you could do this:

```
class SmsParameters {
    ... // Add methods to set parameters, in some non-restrictive way.
    ... // In particular, users should be able to pass login parameters through it
}

class SmsReturn {
    ... // Add methods to harvest the return value, e.g. as an Object
}

interface ISmsService {
     SmsReturn sendSms(SmsParameters args);
}
```

There isn't much the compiler could do in matching vendors to callers, but at least the callers would have only one method to call.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any harm with replacing the two methods with one single method like - `Object sendSms(String...loginid); ` ??

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Returning `Object` is probably fine, but passing `String[]` array , especially as variable arguments, is a bit tricky. It leaves the impression of different vendors requiring different kinds of calls - e.g. you'll see `smsService.sendSms("hello")` in one spot, and `smsService.sendSms()` in the other, which will make readers think of vendor-specific calls even though there's only a single, unified method.

Comment: As far as I grasp It does not prevent the user to call the wrong method.

Comment: Yes, it may get hard for others to comprehend the code.
@cgon I think it makes the method intelligent enough to act as it is required by that specific class.

Answer (score 1):

The interface should be split into two different interfaces, each containing one method. The first class should only implement the first interface, and the second class should only implement the second interface.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing the interface like this

```
public interface ISmsService {

    // Common method, with optional parameter
    Object sendSms(String...loginid);

}
```

And then the implementations could be

```
public class VendorAService implements ISmsService{

    @Override
    public Object sendSms(Strong...loginid) {

        // here you can use the parameter          

        return "send msg via vendor A";
    }
}
```

and

```
public class VendorBService implements ISmsService{

    @Override
    public Object sendSms(Strong...loginid) {

        // here you can ignore the parameter

        return 1000;
    }
}
```

Since the parameter is optional, this would work

```
    ISmsService smsService = new VendorAService();
    smsService.sendSms("12345"); 

    smsService = new VendorBService();
    smsService.sendSms();                    
    smsService.sendSms("random-string");     // not important but, this would work without causing any problems
```